# How to get voidptr out of capsule using python cffi?

Tags: python-c-extension, python-cffi

Is there any way to use cffi to extract the contents of a [capsule](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/capsule.html) and convert it into a voidptr which I can send into C code?

Background info -- numpy arrays can give you a capsule containing a very handy struct, namely the [PyArrayInterface](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.interface.html).  I don't think capsules exist for PyPy yet, so the answer is probably no, but I believe that the future contains capsules for all python versions, so I'm hoping the answer is yes :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so.  Capsules are a way for some CPython C extension modules to pass around pointers; typically, between two different C extension modules.  If you replace one of these modules with a CFFI version, you loose: there is no official way to get the "void *" value from Python, with or without CFFI.  It looks like it would be a valid enhancement.  Feel free to open a feature request here:

https://bitbucket.org/cffi/cffi/issues?status=new&status=open